# Cannot remove leading/trailing white space with gsub or trimws

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to work with a data set that requires significant cleaning. I have one subject name that I cannot seem to remove the leading white space from.

Example data:

```
Data <- dput(Data)
structure(list(Teacher = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Please.rate.teacher:.JOHN.DOE .Overall.rating.for.teacher", 
"Please.rate.teacher: Jane.Doe.Overall.rating.for.teacher"), class = "factor"), 
    Overall_Rating = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L)), .Names = c("Teacher", 
"Overall_Rating"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L
))
```

My attempt at cleaning:

```
Data_clean <- Data %>%
 mutate(Teacher = as.character(Teacher),
Teacher = gsub("Please.rate.teacher|.Overall.rating.for.teacher|[:]", "", Teacher),
            Teacher = gsub("[.]", " ", Teacher),
            Teacher = trimws(Teacher),
            Teacher = tolower(Teacher), Teacher = tools::toTitleCase(Teacher))
```

Results in remaining leading and trailing white space, which also breaks the title case for the second name:

```
unique(Data_clean$Teacher)
[1] "John Doe " " jane Doe"
```

The first name still has trailing white space and the second has leading white space.

How can I remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a completely reproducible example with `stringr` and `str_trim` in particular since I don't know why `trimws` isn't working for you. Your posted code gave me the same output, correctly changing the case to title and removing the spaces.

```r
data <- structure(list(Teacher = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Please.rate.teacher:.JOHN.DOE .Overall.rating.for.teacher", 
              "Please.rate.teacher: Jane.Doe.Overall.rating.for.teacher"), class = "factor"), 
Overall_Rating = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                   3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L)), .Names = c("Teacher", 
                                                                                "Overall_Rating"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L
                                                                                ))

library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  mutate(
    Teacher = Teacher %>%
      str_remove_all("Please.rate.teacher:|.Overall.rating.for.teacher") %>%
      str_replace_all("\\.", " ") %>%
      str_trim() %>%
      str_to_title()
  ) %>%
  `[[`(1) %>%
  unique()
#> [1] "John Doe" "Jane Doe"
```

Created on 2018-03-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks! This works great and I like that it uses `tidyverse`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your data contains a non-ASCII space like `"\u00A0"`. The `trimws` function will only remove ASCII space characters.

Try running `utf8::utf8_print(unique(Data_clean$Teacher), utf8 = FALSE)` to see if this is the case.

To handle non-ASCII spaces, replace `trimws(x)` in your code with

```
gsub("(^[[:space:]]*)|([[:space:]]*$)", "", x)
```

Comment: Your suspicion was correct!
`utf8::utf8_print(unique(Data_clean$Teacher), utf8 = FALSE)
[1] "John Doe\u00a0" "\u00a0jane Doe"`

Comment: glad to hear it. did my suggestion to replace the `trimws` call solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I still got the same result

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Data_clean <- Data %>%
     mutate(Teacher = gsub("Please.rate.teacher|\\s*\\.Overall.rating.for.teacher|:", "", Teacher),
            Teacher = gsub("\\.", " ", Teacher),
            Teacher = trimws(Teacher),
            Teacher = tolower(Teacher), Teacher = tools::toTitleCase(Teacher))

unique(Data_clean$Teacher);
#[1] "John Doe" "Jane Doe"
```

Explanation: Replace optional (`>=0`) whitespaces occurring before `".Overall.rating..."` in `Teacher`.

---

### Sample data

```
Data <- structure(list(Teacher = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Please.rate.teacher:.JOHN.DOE .Overall.rating.for.teacher",
"Please.rate.teacher: Jane.Doe.Overall.rating.for.teacher"), class = "factor"),
    Overall_Rating = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
    3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L)), .Names = c("Teacher",
"Overall_Rating"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L
))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same result:
`[1] "John Doe " " jane Doe"`

Comment: Huh? That's weird. I can't reproduce your output. Can you double-check? I've included the output of `unique(Data_clean$Teacher)`.